# How to apply textures to 3d models

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded the 3d character model. But, the model is not applied textures. Is there a way to apply textures to models in Unity?

Or do I have to create a material myself and attach a texture to it?
I tried this method, but it was difficult when there were multiple textures. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most definitely can you apply textures to models in Unity.

As you have guessed correctly, textures are applied via a `Material`. If you import a model, by default there will be a standard `Material` assigned to it. However, you can also create one yourself and assign it to the `Material` list of the `MeshRenderer` component.

Depending on the shader you choose for your `Material`, there will be different shader properties, including the ones for textures. Usually, there is a `Albedo` property which can be used to set a texture. In the editor, you can simply drag and drop your texture on to it. If you want to apply a texture at runtime, you can set the texture with `yourMaterial.SetTexture(shaderTexturePropertyName e.g. _MainTex)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a 3D model into Unity, it will automatically create a **material** for the model and apply the **textures** to it.

If you are having trouble with the textures not being applied to the model, there are a few things you can try to fix the issue:

First make sure that the textures are in the same folder as the 3D model. Unity will automatically look for textures in the same folder as the model, so if the textures are in a different one, they will not be applied.

Also check the **texture import settings**. When you import a texture into Unity, it will automatically assign certain import settings to the texture. These settings can affect how the texture is applied to the model, so it is important to make sure they are set correctly. To do this, select the texture in the Assets window and then go to the **Inspector** window. In the Inspector window, you will see the **texture import settings**, which you can adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

does the model come with the textures? If you are trying to use your own textures, it might now work because it's not properly "UV Mapped". Or it might work but it will look messy.

If the textures came with the model, then you can just drag and drop the textures into a new material then assign it to the proper mesh.

I can help you better if you can elaborate more on how you are importing your models.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply mew material with variable color,
if the downloaded model is already mapped you can make your own texture map with any image editing software, though it is hard to tell whats going where, you can start with using a checkerboard to test it out.
if its not uv mapped, you need softwares that can do it, unity does not have the ability to create uvmap. 3d software like maya,blender,c4d,3dmax has the ability to create uv map, there are also specific softwares that are just for uv ,[here](https://www.slant.co/topics/2560/%7Ebest-uv-mapping-software) or texturing like substance painter